# Functional tests inside a standalone Symfony2's bundle

Tags: symfony, testing, service, phpunit, bundle

I need to make some functional tests directly in a standalone bundle. I don't want to test a controller, just some interaction between real services.

I would like to know if there is a standard/best way to do that. I did it one way but would like to know if there is a better one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I test a service in symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798143/how-can-i-test-a-service-in-symfony2)

Comment: No, I don't want to execute the tests of the bundle inside an application.

Comment: I gave my own solution in an answer. It's a bit long that's one of the reasons I didn't set it in my question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is my own solution (I summarize all the process for testing in a standalone bundle):

**1. First, a good bundle has its own `composer.json` to define its dependencies:**

```
{
    "name": "my/own-bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "description": "Symfony2 bundle that provides ...",
    "keywords": ["my","own"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john.doe@omg.wtf"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": ">=2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "My\\OwnBundle": "" }
    },
    "target-dir": "My/OwnBundle",
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Note the use of the dependency on `symfony/framework-bundle` which is needed for our tests on services. You certainly can lower the dependencies in specifying your own real dependencies on the symfony core.

With this file I can process the command (do it) to build the vendor directory of my bundle:

```
$ composer update
```

**2. Then, I set my phpunit config file:**

```
<!-- phpunit.xml.dist -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
         bootstrap="Tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="MyOwnBundle Test Suite">
            <directory>./Tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>./Resources</directory>
                <directory>./Tests</directory>
                <directory>./vendor</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**3. Then, I set the php bootstrap for the autoload of the class in my test directory:**

```
// Tests/bootstrap.php

$file = __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
if (!file_exists($file))
{
    $file = __DIR__.'/../../../../../../vendor/autoload.php';
    if (!file_exists($file))
        throw new RuntimeException('Install dependencies to run test suite.');
}

$autoload = require_once $file;
```

These steps are standard for any test in a standalone bundle.

**4. Now, I want to simulate an application to make some functionnal tests on my services:**

I need a kernel class:

```
// Tests/AppKernel.php (you can define it in a subdirectory /Fixtures if you prefer)

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array();

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle();
            $bundles[] = new My\OwnBundle\MyOwnBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config.yml');
    }
}
```

And the corresponding `config.yml`:

```
# Tests/config.yml

framework:
    secret: test
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file

my_own:
    test: 2
```

Here is an example with a mock for the session. Don't forget to specify the correct framework configuration nodes if you want to have access to some services (if you don't specify the node `session`, you have no service `session` for instance).

**5. Finally, I can retrieve my services like the following in my test classes:**

```
// Tests/Functional/Handling/Handler.php

namespace My\OwnBundle\Tests\Functional\Handling;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class HandlerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $handler;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        require_once __DIR__.'/../../AppKernel.php';

        $kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
        $kernel->boot();
        $container = $kernel->getContainer();
        $this->handler = $container->get('my_own.handling.handler');
    }

    public function testHandle()
    {
        $this->assert($this->handler->handle());
    }
}
```