# Symfony2 phpunit run tests on different environment

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm testing email sending in my symfony2 application, I have custom environment that is properly set with email settings and it's able to actually sent emails. I've created environment `test_emails` and I want to run my phpunit tests with it.

phpunit doesn't seem to have this functionality, so my only option is probably create custom bootstrap file, but I can't find anywhere how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The doc about [Environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html) says:

> The `test` environment is used when writing functional tests and is not accessible in the browser directly via a front controller. In other words, unlike the other environments, there is no `app_test.php` front controller file.

So when testing emails you're supposed to use functional test which is well described in [How to Test that an Email is Sent in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/testing.html).

If you want to write a custom bootstrap with some simple logic see: [How to Customize the Bootstrap Process before Running Tests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/bootstrap.html)

Maybe you can actually customize what environment the test harness is using by creating a custom test case that boots the kernel just like here [How can I test a service in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798143/how-can-i-test-a-service-in-symfony2) and then passing an array of options to `bootKernel()` method. See:

- https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Test/KernelTestCase.php#L141
- https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Test/KernelTestCase.php#L168

Answer (score 1):

If your using Symfonys `WebtestCase` you can set the environment as option:

```
$client = static::createClient(array('environment' => 'test-emails'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up creating command that sends all emails I wanted and I can easily switch between environments.

Example:
`php app/console app:emails:test-emails --env=dev`

Answer (score 0):

Use different `phpunit.xml` configuration files for each environment.

```
.
├── phpunit_test_emails.xml
└── phpunit_other_env.xml
```

Run the tests with specific configuration:

```
$ phpunit -c phpunit_test_emails.xml
```

You can set different PHP configurations in the XML configuration file.

You create a custom bootstrap via the `bootstrap` attribute where additional initialisations can be done if needed.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="test/bootstrap.php">

    <!-- ... -->

    <php>
        <includePath>.</includePath>
        <ini name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <const name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <var name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <env name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <post name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <get name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <cookie name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <server name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <files name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <request name="foo" value="bar"/>
    </php>

</phpunit>
```

See the [PHPUnit Manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, but you can't change your symfony environment, this will always run on `test` env.

Comment: You can specify a PHPUnit bootstrap via the bootstrap attribute (see edited answer). But perhaps I misunderstand what is that your trying to do. If what you want is to specify the environment for `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` then define an env constant or variables in the test bootstrap and then in your application bootstrap do an `if TEST_CONSTANT then do this else do that...`.