# Dependency Injection with Fixtures

Tags: symfony

I am building a web application using Symfony 4. I am trying to load fixtures from my functional tests. I have created a fixture class:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class TestFixtures extends Fixture
{
private $encoder;

public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}

public function load(ObjectManager $em)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername('user@gamil.com');
    $user->setIsActive(true);
    $user->setEmail('user@gmail.com');
    $user->setFirstName('John');
    $user->setLastName('Doe');
    $user->setSchool($school);
    $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
    $password = $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, 'pass1234');
    $user->setPassword($password);

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $user;
}

}
```

I have configured services_test.yaml to pass the service to the fixture:

```
services:
_defaults:
    public: true

App\DataFixtures\TestFixtures:
    arguments: ['@security.password_encoder']
```

However, when I try to run my tests I get the following error:

ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\DataFixtures\TestFixtures::__construct(), 0 passed in /Development/app/src/Test/ApiTestCase.php on line 38 and exactly 1 expected

This is the function from my test case:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->client = self::$staticClient;
    $this->purgeDatabase();

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $fixture = new TestFixtures();
    $fixture->load($em);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice offered on this...

Comment: It doesn't matter that you've set the TestFixture service arguments since in your test you're doing new TestFixtures, the registered service and the instance from your test are two different things. Try to retrieve the service from the container instead   https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing https://stackoverflow.com/a/17798257/5988258 . Maybe tell the exact version of symfony if you can't manage to do it

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am currently using Symfony 4.0 but the 4.1 version looks like it could be very helpful in this scenario so I will look into upgrading.

Answer (score 3):

You are instantiating a class:
`$fixture = new TestFixtures();` whereas you need it as a service.
You need to either, do this `$fixture = new TestFixtures(encoder);`
where `encoder` is either an instantiated class or a mock of your encoder class, or, retrieve `TestFixtures` class from the client's container. I'm not entirely sure but try
`$fixture = $this->client->getContainer()->get('App\DataFixtures\TestFixtures');`

Comment: $fixture = $this->client->getContainer()->get('App\DataFixtures\TestFixtures');

Worked perfectly, thanks for your helpful advice :)

Comment: @Domagoj Your answer help me too. Thanks for that. Instead I had the same error in other place. In few fixtures I make sure that fixtures which are needed to load current one were loaded before by: ```public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            UserFixtures::class,
            AnotherFixtures::class,
        ];
    } ``` UserFixtures use Dependency Injection to load needed services and that place cause problem. If I comment UserFixtures::class all fixtures are loaded correctly, if I take care about queue them. Do you have any idea how to make it work?